# Javascript: Sort object array by number properties which include undefined

Tags: javascript

I can define an array of numbers and sort them like this

```js
var array = ['2', undefined, '1'];
array.sort((a, b) => a - b);
console.log(array);
```

The output is `1, 2, null`.

I have an array of objects that can include a number property, which I can define like this. Not all objects have the number property. Now I want to sort this array of objects by the number property. So I tried this:

```js
var array = [
  { number: 2 },
  {},
  { number: 1 }
];
array.sort((a, b) => a.number - b.number);
console.log(array);
```

The output is not what I want. I get `2, undefined, 1`.

If all objects in the array have the number property defined, the same sort function produces `1, 2`, which is the result I would expect.

```js
var array = [
  { number: 2 },
  { number: 1 }
];
array.sort((a, b) => a.number - b.number);
console.log(array);
```

So my question is, what is the best way to sort an array of objects by a property, where the property is not always defined. The intended result is that the objects are ordered by the property (number), with objects that do not define that property at the end of the array.

My only solution so far is to iterate the set, and if the property is not defined, set the property to 0 or `null`. I can then pass the object array to the sort function and it works as I want. Is there a better way than this?

Jfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/t2r6z13e/1/

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can return the difference between the existence of a `number` property on each object being compared, OR return the difference in their `number` properties (in the case that both objects have said properties):

```js
var array = [
  { number: 2 },
  {},
  { number: 1 }
];

array.sort((a, b) => {
  const aHas = typeof a.number !== 'undefined';
  const bHas = typeof b.number !== 'undefined';
  return (bHas - aHas) || (aHas === true && a.number - b.number) || 0;
});
console.log(array);
```

Comment: There are several good solutions posted to this question, including a very concise one from georg. I have accepted this answer as it has wider browser compatibility than georg's answer.

Answer (score 3):

You can provide defaults for array elements with object spreads: `{default, ...item}`

```js
var array = [
  { number: 2 },
  {},
  { number: 1 },
  {},
  { number: 0 },
];

array.sort((a, b) => (
    {number: Number.MAX_VALUE, ...a}.number -
    {number: Number.MAX_VALUE, ...b}.number));

console.log(array);
```

If your target doesn't support object spreads yet, replace them with `Object.assign`.

Comment: So you temporarily assign `Infinity` to the number property, and if there is another `number` property already set the second value overwrites it?

Comment: `Infinity - Infinity` returns `NaN` according to the ECMA-spec. See 11.6.3 in https://www.ecma-international.org/publications/files/ECMA-ST-ARCH/ECMA-262,%201st%20edition,%20June%201997.pdf No idea if this could lead to potential issues, but it's probably good to be aware of ;). A regular callback function in a `sort` method is expected to return `0` opposed to `NaN`.

Comment: This is an excellent solution and is very concise. It has the drawback of not being compatible with Internet Explorer https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax#Browser_compatibility

Answer (score 3):

The explanation is in the comments:

```js
let array = [
  {},
  { number: 2 },
  {},
  { number: 1 }
];

array.sort((a, b) => {
  // two undefined values should be treated as equal ( 0 )
  if( typeof a.number === 'undefined' && typeof b.number === 'undefined' )
    return 0;
  // if a is undefined and b isn't a should have a lower index in the array
  else if( typeof a.number === 'undefined' )
    return 1;
    // if b is undefined and a isn't a should have a higher index in the array
  else if( typeof b.number === 'undefined' )
    return -1;
    // if both numbers are defined compare as normal
  else
    return a.number - b.number;
});

console.log( array );
```

Answer (score 1):

A bit unreadable :

```js
var array = [ { number: 2 }, { }, { number: 1 } ];

array.sort((a, b) => 'number' in a ? 'number' in b ? a.number - b.number : -1 : 1);

console.log(array);
```

Or maybe a bit more readable :

```js
var array = [ { number: 2 }, { }, { number: 1 } ];

array.sort((a, b) => !('number' in a) ? 1 : !('number' in b) ? -1 : a.number - b.number);

console.log(array);
```

Answer (score 0):

If compareFunction is supplied, all non-undefined array elements are sorted according to the return value of the compare function (all undefined elements are sorted to the end of the array, with no call to compareFunction).

In your code, in case of array with number sort function does not call for item with undefined value; while in case of array with object, object is defined but obj.number is not defined, so sort function get call for blank({}) object also and required to add undefined check for *number* in sort function.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest and cleaner way

```
var array = [
  { number: 2 },
  {},
  { number: 1 }
];
array.sort((a, b) => (a.number == undefined ? Number.MAX_VALUE : a.number) - (b.number  == undefined ? Number.MAX_VALUE : b.number) );

console.log(array);
```