# ES6 way to sort an array by value descending, skip undefined values

Tags: javascript, arrays, json

In a JSON array, each object has a key called `popularity` whose value is integer with no quotes.
There are also very few objects in the array which have value as `undefined` for this `popularity` key.
How do you sort the array, using JavaScript (ECMAScript 2015) preferred, by `popularity` key descending largest to smallest, skip or move the `undefined` ones to the bottom.

The following is not working

```
objGroup = objGroup.sort((a,b) => b.popularity - a.popularity ); // or
objGroup = objGroup.sort((a,b) => parseInt(b.popularity) - parseInt(b.popularity) );
```

**EDIT**

found
From [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort):

> In JavaScript 1.2, this method no longer converts undefined elements to null; instead it sorts them to the high end of the array

From the [spec, 15.4.4.11](http://www.ecma-international.org/publications/files/ECMA-ST/ECMA-262.pdf)
:

> Because non-existent property values always compare greater than undefined property values, and
> undefined always compares greater than any other value, undefined property values always sort to the end of the result,
> followed by non-existent property values.

Comment: can you share an example array?

Comment: You’re comparing `b` with itself instead of `a` with `b`. `-` coerces both operands to numbers, so `parseInt` is superfluous. Even if it wasn’t, please use `parseInt` [_with_ the second parameter, `10`](/q/16880327/4642212). Consider using [`Number`](//developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number#Function_syntax) or [`parseFloat`](//developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseFloat) instead.

Comment: There's no such thing as a _"json array"_, _"json object"_ or _"json key"_ ([There's no such thing as a "JSON Object"](http://benalman.com/news/2010/03/theres-no-such-thing-as-a-json/)). `objGroup` is an array of objects.

Comment: _“\[T\]here are also very few \[…\] objects in the array which have value as `undefined` for this `popularity` key”_ — And what do you want to do with those?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Javascript: Sort object array by number properties which include undefined](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56312968/javascript-sort-object-array-by-number-properties-which-include-undefined)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In modern JS you can use `??` to return some  value that is guaranteed to be sorted last if the property is missing, in an older version it can be emulated using a function.

```js
objGroup = [
    {popularity: 1},
    {a:1},
    {popularity: 9},
    {popularity: 2},
    {b:1, popularity: null},
    {popularity: 8},
    {popularity: 3},
    {popularity: 7},
    {c:1},
    {d:1, popularity: undefined},
]

function coalesce(val, def) { 
  if (val === null || typeof val === 'undefined')
    return def
  return val
}

objGroup = objGroup.sort(function (a, b) {
    return coalesce(b.popularity, -Infinity) - coalesce(a.popularity, -Infinity)
})

console.log(objGroup)
```

The quote you're referring to applies to array elements themselves, not to their properties. Example:

```js
a = [
    1,
    void 0,
    9,
    ,,,
    2,
    void 0,
    8
]

console.log(a.sort())
// [1, 2, 8, 9, undefined, undefined, empty × 3]
```

Answer (score 4):

You could sort based on whether the `popularity` is undefined or not. Then sort based on the `popularity`

```js
const input = [{ popularity: 2 }, { popularity: undefined }, { popularity: 1 }],
      isUndefined = o => typeof o.popularity === 'undefined'
      
input.sort((a, b) =>
  isUndefined(a) - isUndefined(b) || (b.popularity - a.popularity)
)

console.log(input)
```