# Different result with Array.sort(comparisonFunction) in Chrome and Firefox

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, firefox

I am using `anArrayOfObjects.sort((a, b) => a.value - b.value)`, where some objects don't have a `value` property.

That leads to different results in Firefox and Chrome, where Chrome seems to sort the object(s) with no `value` property/undefined value to the end, Firefox doesn't.

Is the spec not prescribing the result that Chrome gives, meaning the Firefox result is wrong? Or is that part of the `sort` result up to a particular implementation?

```js
const data2 = [
  { 'name' : 'a', 'value' : 5 },
  { 'name' : 'b', 'value' : 2 },
  { 'name' : 'c' },
  { 'name' : 'd', 'value' : 1 }
];

console.log('before sorting: ', data2);

data2.sort((a, b) => a.value - b.value);

console.log('after sorting: ', data2);
```

Comment: I don't think it's coercion @RoryMcCrossan. The subtraction involving `undefined` is `NaN`, which isn't `< 0`, `> 0` or `=== 0`, so this behaviour is undefined - depending on which way around the implementation checks it may consider that before _or_ after.

Comment: Neither are "wrong". `undefined - 1` and `1 - undefined` both return `NaN`, and `NaN` compared to something is _always_ `false`. The difference between the 2 browsers is probably due to the used sorting algorithm, depending on the order of values beforehand.

Comment: Similar https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56312968/javascript-sort-object-array-by-number-properties-which-include-undefined

Answer (score 3):

Neither are "wrong".

`undefined - undefined`, `undefined - 1` and `1 - undefined` all return `NaN`, and `NaN` compared to something is *always* `false`.

The difference between the 2 browsers is probably due to sorting implementation.
The used sorting algorithm can give different results, depending on the order of values beforehand, and how the implementation deals with `NaN`.

Answer (score 1):

Don't allow browsers engines to decide how to handle your code in doubtful situations, just write your code without it:

```
data2.sort((a, b) => (a?.value || 0) - (b?.value || 0));
```

(Default value could be some small or big number to sort with order you need.)

Comment: Isn't the spec in 4.d.ii of https://tc39.es/ecma262/multipage/indexed-collections.html#sec-array.prototype.sort saying that `+0` is the default value if NaN is returned by the call to the comparison function?

Answer (score 0):

The compare function works as follows:

| `compareFn(a, b)` return value | sort order |
| --- | --- |
| `< 0` | sort `a` after `b` |
| `> 0` | sort `a` before `b` |
| `=== 0` | keep original order of `a` and `b` |

Any subtractions involving `undefined` give a return value of `NaN`, which [per the spec](https://tc39.es/ecma262/multipage/indexed-collections.html#sec-array.prototype.sort), is immediately converted to `0`. However, the order will depend on the specific algorithm used by the implementation, as that determines which values get compared in this way.

The issue becomes clearer when you log out the comparisons:

```js
const data2 = [
  { 'name' : 'a', 'value' : 5 },
  { 'name' : 'b', 'value' : 2 },
  { 'name' : 'c' },
  { 'name' : 'd', 'value' : 1 }
];

console.log('before sorting: ', data2);

data2.sort((a, b) => (console.log(a.value, b.value), a.value - b.value));

console.log('after sorting: ', data2);
```

- **Firefox** seems to be asking `> 0`:

  ```
  5 2
  5 undefined
  undefined 1
  ```

  1. `a` is `'a'` and `b` is `'b'`, return value is `3` so `'a'` is must be after `'b'`.
  2. `a` is `'a'` and `b` is `'c'`, return value is `0` so `'a'` stays before `'c'`.
  3. `a` is `'c'` and `b` is `'d'`, return value is `0` so `'c'` stays before `'d'`.
- **Chrome** seems to be asking `< 0`:

  ```
  2 5
  undefined 2
  undefined 5
  1 5
  1 2
  ```

  1. `a` is `'b'` and `b` is `'a'`, return value is `-3` so `'b'` must be before `'a'`.
  2. `a` is `'c'` and `b` is `'b'`, return value is `0` so `'c'` stays after `'b'`
  3. `a` is `'c'` and `b` is `'a'`, return value is `0` so `'c'` stays after `'a'`
  4. `a` is `'d'` and `b` is `'a'`, return value is `-4` so `'d'` must be before `'a'`
  5. `a` is `'d'` and `b` is `'b'`, return value is `-1` so `'d'` must be before `'b'`

Specifically Chrome doesn't ever compare `'c'` and `'d'` directly, so is never told to keep them in the same order.

Comment: Doesn't the spec in 4.d.ii of https://tc39.es/ecma262/multipage/indexed-collections.html#sec-array.prototype.sort mandate that the comparison value, if the comparison function returns NaN, is a +0? Based on that, is "Given a return value of NaN (which is what you get for any subtraction involving undefined and for which none of those comparisons are true)" true?

Comment: @MartinHonnen yes, you're right; the core (implementation determines which comparisons are made) is correct but I've updated the details.

Answer (score 0):

It is widely known that sorting algorithms are browsers implementation specific, moreover, since there are no *silver bullet* algorithms, a certain browser may use different sorting algorithms for different data shapes as a optimization technique.
This became obvious when looking at the following example results in Firefox:

```js
const arr1 = [
  { 'value' : 5 },
  { 'value' : 2 },
  { 'value': undefined },
  { 'value' : 4 },
  { 'value' : 3 },
  { 'value': undefined },
  { 'value' : 1 },
  { 'value' : 0 }
];

const arr2 = [5, 2, undefined, 4, 3, undefined, 1, 0];

arr1.sort((a, b) => a.value - b.value);

arr2.sort((a, b) => a - b);

console.log(arr1.map(v => `${v.value}`).join());

console.log(arr2.map(v => `${v}`).join());
```

In fact, Chrome results for the above examples are compliant with the [specs](https://tc39.es/ecma262/multipage/indexed-collections.html#sec-array.prototype.sort):

> 4. Let SortCompare be a new Abstract Closure with parameters (x, y) that captures comparefn and performs the following steps when called:
>    a. If x and y are both undefined, return +0.
>    b. If x is undefined, return 1.
>    c. If y is undefined, return -1.

From the above statement can be concluded that `undefined` values always compares greater than any other value, that's why they are sorted at the end.
This result can be achieved with a `merge sort` algorithm with special handling of undefined values, below is a pseudo-code of this:

```js
const mergeSort = arr => {
    let voids = 0;
    const merge = (l, r) => {
        const out = [];
        l.length && l[0] === undefined && (l.shift(), voids++);
        while (l.length && r.length) out.push(l[0] <= r[0] ? l.shift() : r.shift());
        while(l.length) out.push(l.shift());
        while(r.length) out.push(r.shift());
        return out;
    };
    const sort = arr => {
        if (arr.length < 2)
            return arr;
        const m = Math.floor(arr.length / 2);
        const l = arr.slice(0, m), r = arr.slice(m);
        return merge(sort(l), sort(r));
    };
    const result = sort(arr);
    while (voids--) result.push(undefined);
    return result;
};

const arr = [5, 2, undefined, 4, 3, undefined, 1, 0];

console.log(mergeSort(arr).map(v => `${v}`).join());
```

About the *sorted array of objects* result in Firefox, in the first example, it can be obtained with a simple `insertion sort` algorithm, as below:

```js
const insertionSort = arr => {
    for (let i = 1; i < arr.length; i++) {
        let x = i - 1, n = arr[i];
        for (; x >= 0 && arr[x] > n; x--)
            arr[x + 1] = arr[x];
        arr[x + 1] = n;
    }
    return arr;
};

const arr = [5, 2, undefined, 4, 3, undefined, 1, 0];

console.log(insertionSort(arr).map(v => `${v}`).join());
```

Comment: Note that the rules about `x` and `y` being `undefined` are **not** relevant here. `x` and `y` (or `a` and `b` in MDN's nomenclature) are _both_ defined, they're objects. It's their _property_ that is not defined in some cases, which leads to the comparator returning `NaN`.

Comment: Agree that for OP example the `Abstract Closure` can be ignored and we should consider only the result of user defined `comparefn`. Added that just to show it is not the case in Chrome, as it for some reasons applies that rule anyway (however not if we do `b.value - a.value`).